# ShareKit Twitter PIN при авторизации

Tags: twitter, ios

Использую `ShareKit` в `iOS`, поправил всё в соответствии с [could not authenticate OAuth while using twitter from sharekit in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731394/could-not-authenticate-oauth-while-using-twitter-from-sharekit-in-iphone-app), начал авторизовывать.

После авторизации показывает экран с `PIN` и требованием его куда-то ввести.
Подскажите, что с этим делать? При шаринге как я понимаю, не должно ничего лишнего пользователем вводиться.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1RI2OUO.png]

Comment: Ваш вопрос решен? Если да, сделайте ответ из своего комментария и примите свой вопрос, как правильный, чтобы закрыть ... вопрос))).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, всё дело в настройках на dev.twitter.com. Для приложения нужно установить там `callback url` и поставить `checkbox` разрешающий логин через это приложение.

После данных манипуляций `PIN` не спрашивает, но и авторизация не работает полностью. Чтобы всё работало - использовать последнюю версию `ShareKit` с гитхаба: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit На официальном сайте далеко не самая последняя версия.